# Inserting 3 keys in row into hash with linear probe, what is the probability of 4th element requires 3 probes

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, probability, hashcode

Inserting 3 keys in row into hash with linear probe, what is the probability of 4th element requires 3 probes?, I am getting 12/n^3, because after inserting 1st element, there are 3 places you can insert for the 2nd element(left of 1st Element, 1st element, right of 1st elemenet) that is 3/n. and 3rd element you have 4 places to insert to make them consecutive so 4/n and last 4th element has to be inserted in to 1st element's hash so 1/n. Probability is 3/n *4/n *1/n =12/n^3      or it is just 12/n^2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a (pair of) cases where the first two elements are not adjacent but the third element fills the gap.   Math is similar though 3/n*4/n + 2/n*2/n = 16/n^2 to get the three adjacent and then the 1/n odds of hitting the first one to give 16/n^3.